# class & object function not working as intended (reads only the first line of file)

Tags: python, function, class, object, csv

I have a file with the class and it's function

```
import csv

class file:
    def __init__(self,rc):   
        self.rc = rc

    def load(self):
        with open('airports.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            for row in file: #csv.reader(file):
                return(row)
```

which reads a csv file with many (40,000) lines and

```
with open('airports.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            for row in file: #csv.reader(file):
                return(row)
```

this code a lone reads all the rows as intended, but when i use the first code above with this

```
from testing import file

file1 = file("row")

print (file1.load())
```

it only returns the first row of the csv file. why does this occur, and how can i fix it?

Comment: What are you expecting those to do?

Comment: Do not name your class 'file' and then make a variable called 'file' too. It is confusing and poor form. You class should be 'class MyCSVFile(object)' or the like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `return` the first row, which ends the `load()` method and ignores the rest of the file. You should `yield` the row instead, making a generator method. You can then call this to print out all lines:

```
print('\n'.join(str(l) for l in file1.load()))
```

Comment: I think this is unnecessarily complex for someone who's obviously new to programming. OP should not be iterating inside the method at all, but simply return the file object.